# iPad Landscape messing up touches began

Tags: ipad, uiview, touches, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

My app is only allowable in the landscape orientations, and it launches in landscape. Thus, the top left corner when the iPad is landscape is (0,0), so everything works fine.

However, when I pick up "touchesBegan"...it isn't working properly. Only when I tap on like the right two-thirds of the iPad does it pick up the touches. I know it has something to do with the orientation, because the app is literally just blank screen with a single UIView and nothing else. It is quite simple. There are no other possible problems that would cause this.

To be sepecific, if I print out the x location in the touchesBegan function, and if the iPad is held with the home button on the left, the width is 1024. And 1024-768 is 256. This is exactly the x position where it begins to sense my touches. Anything to the left of x=256 does not sense the touches.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Struts and Springs and make sure that whatever should pick up the touches is covering the whole area and locked to the 4 sides.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with these words. Can you clarify and specify?

Comment: my app is done programatically without xib...can you show me programatically how to do this?

Comment: (Thanks NJones for the image).

Expanding on Neo's answer: if the device is already in the desired orientation when the app launches it will not call that function so maybe the best place to add the resizing code will probably be viewWillAppear.

Comment: Yeah, what Fernando said is true. Like I mentioned in my other comment, you can place that appFrame and the other line [self.view setFrame:] in viewWillAppear.

Comment: I did that in viewWillAppear as well. It still thinks the width is 768 and the height is 1024...which is backwards.

Comment: Are you sure you're allowing only landscape and not portrait instead? How did you set it to allow only landscape?

Comment: I went in and defined "Supported interface orientations (iPad)"

Comment: The code equivalent of autoresizing in IB (pictured) is `self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

Comment: @CodeGuy If your instantiating without a xib then what does your implementation of loadView look like?

Answer (score 0):

To do it programmatically,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height)];
return YES; 
// if you want to support only LANDSCAPE mode, use the line below
/*
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
*/
}
```

This sets the view to occupy the full screen.

Comment: it still does not think i'm touching the screen in landscape mode, as I described above in my question

Comment: Of course, you can set the frame anywhere you want (view init or elsewhere before the view is actually displayed)! I was just giving an example which supports multiple orientations. :)

Comment: so then how do I define the "touchable" area...because it is operating as if I'm in portrait mode, however the graphics are operating in landscape mode

Comment: @CodeGuy I just implemented a small sample project and it works just fine for me!

<pre>
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch * touch in touches) {
        NSLog(@"%f; %f", [touch locationInView:self.view].x, [touch locationInView:self.view].y);
    }
}
</pre>

Comment: can you post code for all the code of the project? because it's still not working for me

Comment: when I print self.view in that function you posted...it gives the wrong frame coordinates

Comment: I don't understand about what you mean by "wrong frame coordinates". http://pastebin.com/h7fXRhim (SampleController.m); http://pastebin.com/nbfKPQ2g (SampleController.h);

Comment: I just have what I posted in the answer. So I don't even see the point of pasting the code. :)

Comment: I think it's best that you paste your code, if it still doesn't work for you. I really am unable to think of what might be going wrong with your code.

Comment: The point is that giving me 3 lines of code is not a project. Can you give me the whole project? Because clearly, I have used your code, and it is not working. The original problem still exists. Please read my question careuflly.

Comment: lol.. there is NOTHING ELSE in my project! Like I said, it was a small sample I created JUST now. Anyway, I am sick of trying to answer your question without even seeing what code you wrote. All the best! Let the world know what went wrong. Maybe it will help someone else later.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7594/discussion-between-neo-and-codeguy)

Comment: oh, so you make a project with one function, no class variables, no app delegate, etc?!?!??!?!?!?

Comment: I don't even know why I am responding to this chap.. God help me.. http://www.filefactory.com/file/c2771fb/n/Sample.zip

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that, when defining the UIWindow, it needs to be defined as

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

and not strict coordinates.