# UIView frame changing coordinates in iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

strong textI have an iPad app which only allows landscape orientation, and launches in landscape orientation. I have a `UIViewController` and in the `viewDidLoad` I set the frame of the view:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 728);
```

In a `touchesBegan` function in that same `UIViewController` I print out the view:

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.view);
```

and when I tap the screen get:

```
<UIView: 0x37e370; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); transform = [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; layer = <CALayer: 0x37e3d0>>
```

As you can see, the frame changes to [0,0,768,1024] (which is portrait iPad) instead of [0,0,1024,728] (which is what I defined it to be in the `viewDidLoad` method).

Why is it switching on me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to this other question of yours, no? [iPad Landscape messing up touches began](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254136/ipad-landscape-messing-up-touches-began/9254159#9254159)

Quoting your answer:
" is that, when defining the UIWindow, it needs to be defined as

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

and not strict coordinates.
"